# Codeigniter query builder, I cant extract my Row and returns null even if there are data in tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my code with error

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row()`

```
$query = $this->db->select( 'a.*, b.feild1 as feild1, b.feild2 as feild2' )
                    ->from('game as a')
                    ->join('transaction as b', 'a.transactionID = b.transactionID', 'left')
                    ->where('a.clientID', $clientID)
                    ->order_by('a.transactionID', 'DESC')
                    ->limit(1);
                    ->row();    
$row = $query->row();
```

then i used get(); and encoded to json format and I have all response null

all Null values even thou there is data in my tables. 
the query builder produces this

```
SELECT a.*,b.field as 'feild', b.field2 as 'field2'
FROM (game as a)
LEFT JOIN transaction as b ON a.transactionID = b.transactionID
WHERE a.clientID =  1234
ORDER BY a.transactionID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed `->row();` added get

Try some thing like this

```
public function some_function_name($clientID) {
  $this->db->select('a.*, b.feild1 as feild1, b.feild2 as feild2' );
  $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'game as a');
  $this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix . 'transaction as b', 'a.transactionID = b.transactionID', 'left');
  $this->db->where('a.clientID', $clientID);
  $this->db->order_by('a.transactionID', 'DESC');
  $this->db->limit(1);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->row_array();
}
```

Or

```
public function some_function_name($clientID) {
  $this->db->select('a.*, b.feild1 as feild1, b.feild2 as feild2' );
  $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'game a');
  $this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix . 'transaction b', 'a.transactionID = b.transactionID', 'left');
  $this->db->where('a.clientID', $clientID);
  $this->db->order_by('a.transactionID', 'DESC');
  $this->db->limit(1);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->row_array();
}
```